# Reading the value of an input using XPath, then using in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, xpath, greasemonkey

I'm using this XPath to get the value of a field:

```
//input[@type="hidden"][@name="val"]/@value
```

I get several results, but I only want the first. Using

```
//input[@type="hidden"][@name="val"]/@value[1]
```

Doesn't work. Once I have this, how do I pick up the value in Greasemonkey? I am trying things like:

```
alert("val " + val.snapshotItem);
```

But I think that's for the node, rather than the string.

Answer (score 19):

For the XPath, try:

```
//input[@type="hidden" and @name="val" and position() = 1]/@value
```

For use in a GreaseMonkey script, do something like this:

```
var result = document.evaluate(
  "//input[@type='hidden' and @name='var' and position()=1]/@value",
  document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
);

var hiddenval = result.snapshotItem(0);

if (hiddenval)
  alert("Found: " + hiddenval.nodeValue);  
else
  alert("Not found.");
```

Strictly speaking: Using `"position()=1"` in the XPath filter is not absolutely necessary, because only the first returned result is going to be used anyway (via `snapshotItem(0)`). But why build a larger result set than you really need.

EDIT: Using an XPath result of the `ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE` type makes sure you get the nodes in *document order*. That means the first node of the result will also be the first node in the document.

Answer (score 4):

Tomalak has the right idea, but I'd do it a bit differently.

```
var result = document.evaluate(
  "//input[@type='hidden' and @name='var']",
  document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);

var input = result.iterateNext();

if (input)
  alert("Found: " + input.value);  
else
  alert("Not found.");
```

This way, you're specifying as part of the *result set* that you want only one item returned (the first one in the document, in this case). Also, here you're fetching the DOM node and then reading its `value` property to get the value. I've found this to be more reliable than fetching a string value through XPath (though your mileage may vary).

Comment: You are right. I'll adapt my code a bit. I tend to forget that FF has XPath that is able to work out of document order. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

One possibility is to include jQuery in your scripts. This will provide a simpler syntax for accessing elements.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           MyScript
// @namespace      http://example.com
// @description    Example
// @include        *
//
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var input = $("input[type='hidden'][name='var']");

if (input) {
  alert("Found: " + input.val());  
} else {
  alert("Not found.");
}
```